# Copy code from Visual Studio 2022 with line numbers

Tags: visual-studio

How do I copy code from Visual Studio 2022 with the line numbers?
I need to paste my code into Microsoft Word with line numbers.

I tried to insert a table in Word where the left column is a line number (1..enter..2..enter..3..enter), and the right column is code from Visual Studio, but that approach was too slow.